# How can I link from homepage to another details page depending on a specific argument in for loop? - Django

Tags: python, django

I am learning django and during a project given I've stuck in linking the home.html to specific details.html

My code is the following:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('details/<statename>', views.details, name='details')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# This is the dictionary for all the attractions
attractions = [
  { 'attraction_name' : 'Niagra Falls', 'state' : 'New York'},
  { 'attraction_name' : 'Grand Canyon National Park', 'state' : 'Arizona'},
  { 'attraction_name' : 'Mall of America', 'state' : 'Minnesota'},
  { 'attraction_name' : 'Mount Rushmore', 'state' : 'South Dakota'},
  { 'attraction_name' : 'Times Square', 'state' : 'New York'},
  { 'attraction_name' : 'Walt Disney World', 'state' : 'Florida'}
]

def home(request):
  # The context is all of the variables we want passed into the template.
  context = {"attractions" : attractions}
  return render(request, 'tourist_attractions/home.html', context)

def details(request, statename):
  # We replace the dash with a space for later ease of use. The dash is there because of the slugify filter.
  context = {"attractions" : attractions, "statename" : statename.replace("-", " ")}
  return render(request, 'tourist_attractions/details.html', context)
```

**home.html** (I tried to link from `home` page to `details/<statename>` page using for loop)

```
{% block content %}
<h1>This is a list of attractions in America!</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Attraction</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>State details</th>
  </tr>
  {% for item in attractions|dictsort:"state" %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.attraction_name }}</td> # included in the task
    <td>{{ item.state }}</td> # included in the task
    <td><a href="{% url 'details' statename=item.state %}">click here</a></td> # Not in the task but I assumed that after clicking each link, the link should lead the user to that details/<statename>

    <td>{{ item.attraction_name }}</td> 
    <td>{{ item.state }}</td> 
    <!--I would like the link to lead the user to that details/<statename> url-->
    <td><a href="{% url 'details' statename=item.state %}">click here</a></td> 
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

Later, I have created `details.html` of which if I type the url `details/arizona` or `details/new-york`, the url details/ works well.

The problem is I cannot click the link from the home page to details page when states' names have space in names, for example, when I want to see more details for Times Square in 'New York'. I would like to know how I can link from home to details/ correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? and if not where is the page redirecting?

Comment: Everything is OK. I'm able to click in every link. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Astros @Corralien It said `400 bad request` when I clicked a link for state "New York" and "South Dakota"

Comment: Ok but what is the url you're getting redirected to?

Answer (score 0):

Having spaces in url does not work well in general. What I would suggest you (and which is commonly used) is to create a new field in your State model which would be a slug, computed from the state name. Slugs are URL-proof strings built from a non-URL proof string (like name with spaces). Then you could use this new field as a URL variable (instead of the name).

To compute slugs, I often use `python-slugify`: https://github.com/un33k/python-slugify

Say you have a State model with `state` field (which contains state's name) :

```py
from django.db import models
from slugify import slugify

class State(models.Model):
    # Some fields
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.state)
```

Then in your templates, just replace `item.state` by `item.slug` for URL matching.